# Redirection/login with Salesforce portal

Tags: html, authentication, salesforce

Having an issue with a salesforce login on our site. When the customer fills in the information, it submits but then takes them to the login portal again to enter the information, like it doesn't remember what was just entered.

Any way we can fix this?

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li id="login">
            <a id="login-trigger" href="#">
                                Log In <span>▼</span></a>
            <div id="login-content">
                <form action="https://na6.salesforce.com/secur/login_portal.jsp" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" value="00D80000000anEa" name="orgId" />
                    <input type="hidden" value="060800000006ANB" name="portalId" />
                    <input type="hidden" value="true" name="useSecure" />
                    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="loginType" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="loginAction" />
                    <fieldset id="inputs">
                        <input id="txtUserIdGutter" class="InputText" type="text" name="Email"
                        placeholder="Your email address" tabindex="1" />
                        <input id="txtPasswordGutter" class="InputText" type="password" name="Password"
                        placeholder="Password" />
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset id="actions">
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in" />
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />Keep me signed in</label>
                        <label>
                            <a href="https://na6.salesforce.com/secur/forgotpasswordp.jsp?orgId=00D80000000anEa&amp;portalId=060800000006ANB&amp;pLu=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.carrierstore.com%2F">Forgot Password?</a>
                        </label>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: We're going to need to see your server side code.

Comment: @Desperado24: You've made an HTML form, that's great, but without a server-side code to process it, you've done nothing really

Comment: He's using Salesforce... there is no server-side code for him to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get in touch with Salesforce's developer support team.

Comment: Yea, this really has us stumped. The slightest thing wrong and SalesForce will act like a little child. We thought that it might be with our code, but maybe not